# Convergence of $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{z^2}{k^2}\right)$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Study the convergence of :
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{z^2}{k^2}\right)$$

$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{z^2}{k^2}\right) \  \text{converges} \Leftrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \textrm{Log}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{k^2}\right)$$
Now since $$\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{\left|\textrm{Log}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{k^2}\right)\right|}{\left|\frac{z^2}{k^2}\right|} = 1$$

And $$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^2}{k^2}$$

Converges for $|z| < k$ which implies that $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{z^2}{k^2}\right)$ is convergent for $|z|<k$

In fact the convergence is absolute .

Now to study the uniform convergence using the M-test for infinite products

$$\text{on} \ \ \ |z|< k \left|\frac{-z^2}{k^2}\right| \leq M_k$$

Where $M_k = \frac{r^2}{k^2}$  , $r \geq \text{max}|z| $ in the region

Now $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{r^2}{k^2}= \frac{1}{r^2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} \ \ \text{which is convegent }$$

which implies that $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{z^2}{k^2}\right)$ converges uniformly in $|z| < k$

Is my solution correct ? Or Is any thing is missing in my solution ?

Thank you ...

Comment: $\sum \frac{z^2}{k^2}$ converges for every $z$ since you're multiplying $\zeta(2)$ by $z^2$

Comment: What is $k$ in $|z| < k$ ? You need to say that the series $f_n(z) = \sum_{k=n}^\infty \log(1-\frac{z^2}{k^2})$ converges uniformly for say $|z| < n/2$ and use that $g_n(z) = \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (1-\frac{z^2}{k^2})$ converges uniformly too, thus (the infinite product) $g_n(z) e^{f_n(z)}$ converges uniformly for $|z| < n/2$

Comment: $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Your answer makes no sense.  That product does not depend on any parameter $k$, since $k$ is a bound variable.

Comment: the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^2}{k^2}$ doesnt converge uniformly in $\Bbb C$ because $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^2}{k^2}=z^2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}=z^2\frac{\pi^2}6$. Anyway the series converges locally uniformly.

Comment: I didn't say that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^2}{k^2}$ converges uniformly in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: The infinite product is uniformly and absolutely convergent in any closed bound region .